# Video preview not working for *.avi files

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a sample of my code.

```js
$("#videoSubmit").click(function() {
  var video = document.createElement("video");
  video.setAttribute("controls", "");
  var source = document.createElement("source");
  source.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.querySelector('input[id=file_v]').files[0]);
  alert(source.src);
  $(video).append(source);
  $("#post").append(video);
  $("#vid").hide();
});
$("#video").click(function() {
  $("#vid").show();
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="video" class="bar">Insert Video</button>
<form action='Post' method='post'>
  <div contenteditable="true" id='post'></div><br>
  <!--input type='submit'/-->
</form>
<fieldset style="background: beige; position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 300px; left: 300px;" id="vid" hidden>
  <h2>Insert Video</h2><input type="file" id="file_v" /><button id="videoSubmit">Add Video</button></fieldset>
```

I want to insert a preview of the video which I will later work with using java. It works with every file extension apart from *.avi files. Thanks in advance

Comment: Its is working for me

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: AVI is just a container (as ZIP or RAR), video and audio themselves can use many different codecs which your browser may or may nor support. Have you verified that your browser can actually play the trouble files, e.g. by dragging then into a browser window?